# How to get a table in the Correct Place with LaTeX

Tags: tables

Hi I am using LaTeX through no choice of my own. I thought I had just gotten used to it and then it starts messing around with me. My out put is to a PDF document.

I am trying to add 6 tables to the Appendix of my Document here is my code.

```
\section{Appendix}

\subsection{Project 1}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\caption{Description of the Project}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
   What Is the Size of the Project? & Large \\
   Who are the Stakeholders Involved? & 
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Business Analyst
    \item Business Owner
    \item Developer
\end{enumerate}\\   
    What Is the Main Form of Communication for the Team? & Verbal \\
    Is the Team Located Across Multiple Sites? & Yes \\
    Will the Project be Handed Over to a Different Team Upon Completion? & No \\
    What Stage will the Project be in Upon Completion? & Next Stage \\
\end{tabular}  
\label{tab:myfirsttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\caption{Recommended Portfolio}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
  Maintained Portfolio & Recommended Portfolio \\
  \hline    
\end{tabular}  
\label{tab:myfirsttable}
\end{table}

\subsection{Protect 2}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  
\caption{Description of the Project}
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
  What Is the Size of the Project? & Small \\
  Who are the Stakeholders Involved? & 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Database Modeller
    \item Business Analyst
    \item Business Owner
    \item Scrum Master
    \item Tester
    \item Developer
  \end{enumerate}\\
    What Is the Main Form of Communication for the Team? & Verbal \\
    Is the Team Located Across Multiple Sites? & No \\
    Will the Project be Handed Over to a Different Team Upon Completion? & No \\
    What Stage will the Project be in Upon Completion? & Next Stage \\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:hresult}
\end{table}

 \begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
 \caption{Recommended Portfolio}
 \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{4cm}}
    Maintained Portfolio & Recommended Portfolio \\
    \hline    
  \end{tabular}  
  \label{tab:myfirsttable}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{paper}

\end{document}
```

There is a 3rd Section that is laid out the same. The second and third table are created in the middle of my references. I have tried going through each of the tables line by line to debug it but they seem to break as I add in rows. I have tried using `[h]`, `[H]` and `[h!]` but none of these have helped. In fact `[H]` broke the first 2 table also. The tables are in my TeX file in the place that I want them to generate.

Comment: With `\usepackage{float}` in the preamble, `[H]` will place the float at the exact place it is placed in the code. What warnings/errors did you get when you tried that?

Comment: Duplicate of [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2282). See also [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) for a detailed explanation.